# Playframework - will they continue to update 1.* or will they focus solely on 2.*?

Tags: scala, playframework

Will playframework continue update their 1.* version or will they discontinue it and will focus on 2.*? Latest release was 2.0.4, Oct 01 2012. I am asking because if they discontinue 1.* then I have been thinking about learning Scala.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They will not. As said in many places 1.x branch is currently in maintenance mode, which means, that there will be no more features added into it. Play 2+ is current active branch.

On the other hand, you don't need (almost) to learn Scala, you can just use the Java version of Play 2. Only part where basic Scala knowledge will be required will be configs and views, however that's a task for just one day...

Answer (score 1):

Well, this really depends on what you mean by discontinue. Play 1.3 is currently work in progress. It is a major release (i.e. not 1.2.6) because it doesn't work with previous versions of Java (Java 5 and previous are out, I believe). But the fact a new version is coming out, shows that it is being worked on.

However, it is a smaller number of developers than is on the 2.x branch. 1.3 is also mainly bug fixes and upgrades to libraries, rather than actively adding new features, as most new features are being poured into the 2.x branch.

So, the simple answer is Yes and No, depending on how you want to look at it.